# File saved on the wrong google folder

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an issue saving a file into a folder using Google Apps Script. My problem is our Google Drive has many folders with duplicated names. For instance, the folder `2022` appears four times in different subfolders. My issue is when I try to save a file with Apps Script, it saves in a different folder. I used the script I saw in one of the posts here:

```
var par_fdr = DriveApp.getFolderById(123456789A); // replace the ID
var fdr_name = "child_fdr";

try {
  var newFdr = par_fdr.getFoldersByName(fdr_name).next();
}
catch(e) {
  var newFdr = par_fdr.createFolder(fdr_name);
}
```

I tried other scripts and was doing the same thing. I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The function will display the folders if there are more than one and provide the user with the option to select the desired folder based upon it's current path.

```
function main() {
  const foldername = "abcd";//folder name being searched for
  let fldrs = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(foldername);
  let fA = [];
  let newFldr;
  while (fldrs.hasNext()) {
    let fldr = fldrs.next();
    let fid = fldr.getId();
    fA.push({ id: fid, path: getPathAllDrivesFromId(fid) });
  }
  if (fA && fA.length > 1) {
    let s = fA.reduce((a, c, i) => ( a += `${i + 1} - Path: ${c.path}\n`,a ), `Enter number 1 through ${fA.length} - \n`);
    let r = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Select Desired Folder", s , SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
    if (r.getSelectedButton() == SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.OK && parseInt(r.getResponseText()) > 0 && parseInt(r.getResponseText()) < fA.length + 1) {
      newFldr = DriveApp.getFolderById(fA[parseInt(r.getResponseText()) - 1].id).createFolder(foldername)
    } else {
      return;
    }
  } else {
    newFldr = DriveApp.getFolderById(fA[0].id).createFolder(foldername);
  }
}
```

Support function to return folder paths so that you can hopefully select the one you want

```
function getPathAllDrivesFromId(fileid) {
  var ids = [{id:fileid,name:DriveApp.getFileById(fileid).getName()}];
  let r;
  do {
    r = Drive.Files.get(fileid,{supportsAllDrives:true,supportsTeamDrives:true});
    if(r.parents.length > 0) {
      //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(r.parents[0]));
      ids.push({id:r.parents[0].id,name:DriveApp.getFolderById(r.parents[0].id).getName()});
      fileid = r.parents[0].id
    }
  }while (r.parents.length > 0);
  if(ids[ids.length - 1].name == "Drive") {
    ids[ids.length - 1].name = Drive.Drives.get(ids[ids.length - 1].id).name;
  }
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(ids));
  let path = ids.map(obj => obj.name).flat().reverse().join(' / ')
  //Logger.log(path);
  return path;
}
```

The Prompt Dialog:

[image]